# fetch() function in react-native throws 'Network Request Failed' error

Tags: react-native, networking, fetch

react-native fetch() works fine in localhost, but throws 'Network request failed'if pointed to web module of the application.can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Give us some code, some logs, some context.. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24627 for your reference

Answer (score 1):

You need to post more details but for start, Try working with postman on some other computer. If error still happens, you have some problem with your server.

Comment: Hi @usman, I have tested in postman.Its working only when I disable SSL verification certificate in postman. Should I need to do changes in recat native for this issue or we should do settings in web server

Comment: Can I use react-native-ssl-pinning library

Comment: I would suggest make changes in server. It would be better to handle this on the server side

Comment: You need to give details of server first. What framework are you using